# My domain is not working in my server even when the DNS are correct

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

My domain is not working and show this when i visit it:

[image]
My domain should work even with ssl and is:

```
https://www.descubreteotihuacan.com/
```

And my DNS are configure like this:
[image]

My primary DNS pointing as CNAME is `ns1.vuelosenglobos.mx` and i use it like this because **i don't use static public ip because mine change everyday so thats why i use a CNAME** Right now `ns1.vuelosenglobos.mx` resolve `189.139.58.126` which is actually my server ip right now.

So, what i'm doing wrong? Why my domain it's not working. I left pass 4 hours until now, so i think i gave really enough time to wait dns refresh.

For example, i have the same dns settings to another domain which works perfectly on this same server with this dns (`www.festivaldeglobos.mx`):

[image]

Thanks.

> I have `descubreteotihuacan.com` configured in godaddy like the next image to get a link between my domain and my server:

[image]

**EDIT**

I was trying to make a ping with `cmd` and i got this:

[image]

For some reason this is returning a wrong public ip.

So, i've checked in DNS Propagation Checker and looks that in some countries my domain is taking the good real ip, while in other some doesn't

[image]

Comment: What is your issue? What do you see/what should you see? Note your very first screenshot show both an A and a CNAME record defining www.descubreteotihuacan.com records, same thing in the second screenshot for www.festivaldeglobos.mx. That sounds wrong. You either have one CNAME, or 1+ A records. Both A and CNAME should not be valid. When in doubt, mxtoolbox.com is usually a good starting point.

Comment: yeah,, i know CNAME and A record won't be valid, so as you can see in my godaddy dns settings i just added CNAME record so i don't know where A record is coming from, i'll edit my question being more clear about my issue

Comment: ok, edited my question, could you see it?

Comment: As far as I can see, right now, I'ld say it works: www.descubreteotihuacan.com resolves to ns1.vuelosenglobos.mx, then to 189.139.58.126.

Comment: oh, yeah. Makes perfect sense. Your browser is looking for descubreteotihuacan.com. You don't have an A (nor CNAME) record there.

Comment: Thanks @SYN I don't know why but from my side visiting https://www.descubreteotihuacan.com or http://www.descubreteotihuacan.com i'm not seeing anything, i'll update my image in the question

Comment: visiting http://www.descubreteotihuacan.com/, I do have a Forbidden error, which would suggest your webserver does not allow me in, ... your DNS sounds allright

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102734/discussion-between-fernando-urban-and-syn).

Comment: thank you all, issue solved after a full conversation with @SYN and a really awaiting reponse for the dns cache, happy new year to everyone